# selenium webdriver bot to extract bokeh images from local html

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, bokeh

How to improve this script?
How to save more than one image per one run.

The html with 3 graphs loads instantly, but html with 50 graphs loads a few minutes. So it's not an optimal way to reload page for each image.

I'm getting only one image per one run. After that I get the error
Message: 
stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document.

```
# encoding: utf-8 

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import os

import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver")

url = 'file:\\\\\\%s/26w0.html' % (os.getcwd())

driver.get(url)
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("bk-tool-icon-save")
saves = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("bk-tool-icon-save")

for i in range(len(saves)):
    print i
    driver.get(url)
    elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("bk-tool-icon-save")
    saves = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("bk-tool-icon-save")

    saves[i].click()
    elem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

It's written on python, but I'm open to suggestions,
and if you know the solution on java/.net/any other platform/language, you are welcome.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Bokeh Plot</title>
        
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.4.min.css" type="text/css" />
        
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Bokeh.set_log_level("info");
</script>
        <style>
          html {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
          }
          body {
            width: 90%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: auto;
          }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="bk-root">
            <div class="bk-plotdiv" id="c5c2aae1-5936-42f6-b4e3-9bc4b46efd06"></div>
        </div>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function() {
          var fn = function() {
            Bokeh.safely(function() {
              var docs_json = {"2797a004-7f17-48fa-b80f-105be766d58d":{"roots":{"references":[{"attributes":{"fill_alpha":{"value":0.1},"fill_color":{"value":"#1f77b4"},"line_alpha":{"value":0.1},"line_color":{"value":"#1f77b4"},"size":{"units":"screen","value":8},"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"bb128c3f-68fb-4464-9d3f-c188b2ce8614","type":"Circle"},{"attributes":{"plot":{"id":"64a90e8d-fce9-4bbd-b044-1ceda097ba2d","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"ab09a83a-42c4-44e8-919d-30796ac60bfe","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"b2cbd3ba-7dbd-400e-9971-227edc77fed7","type":"Grid"},{"attributes":{"format":"%.1f ml"},"id":"de7cb3ad-08b7-45c5-9050-03c4b3621d74","type":"PrintfTickFormatter"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"83b66900-4cd4-4d1c-8f66-60c8665f23e6","type":"ColumnDataSource"},"glyph":{"id":"5e858549-3ff5-41e0-b90c-d3a6976a3686","type":"Line"},"hover_glyph":null,"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"e6565ecc-8d83-440f-af86-88b488066471","type":"Line"},"selection_glyph":null},"id":"d7941470-1f87-439f-a797-accc78f7cc69","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{"label":{"value":"75x^4 - 542.17x\u00b3 + 396.6x\u00b2 + 131.48x + 2.0519"},"renderers":[{"id":"9b3e35b4-210e-4989-a5c3-8015c3ae34bc","type":"GlyphRenderer"}]},"id":"6f8cc559-bea7-4209-99c5-7037deead29c","type":"LegendItem"},{"attributes":{"callback":null,"column_names":["x","y"],"data":{"x":[0.5,1,2,4,6],"y":[0.183,0.436,0.771,1.453,2.177]}},"id":"32b7f2b8-c72e-4caf-982d-49753e787111","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{"format":"%.1f ml"},"id":"e4ec96e3-88cc-4a38-9c98-013e60302040","type":"PrintfTickFormatter"},{"attributes":{"axis_label":"OD=450nm","axis_label_text_font_style":"bold","formatter":{"id":"de7cb3ad-08b7-45c5-9050-03c4b3621d74","type":"PrintfTickFormatter"},"plot":{"id":"e44c3f42-efae-400d-a997-de22cc1d9be2","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"8ab7c0bd-3ec6-4ba1-992b-9b1d81e19180","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"bf5574c8-01bd-4feb-9dc1-f2d43e3ff684","type":"LinearAxis"},{"attributes":{"fill_color":{"value":"white"},"line_color":{"value":"#1f77b4"},"size":{"units":"screen","value":8},"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"eda96e22-e71f-4452-a30f-b9a4b8718831","type":"Circle"},{"attributes":{"dimension":1,"plot":{"id":"64a90e8d-fce9-4bbd-b044-1ceda097ba2d","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"2e431824-d01c-4cce-abac-39320d6671b2","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"291ccc16-e4c1-4f7e-bae5-af652e9fd098","type":"Grid"},{"attributes":{},"id":"e4c1cac9-ed55-4ac3-8af2-e2390e64ddaa","type":"BasicTicker"},{"attributes":{"callback":null,"column_names":["x","y"],"data":{"x":[10,20,40,80,160],"y":[0.183,0.436,0.771,1.453,2.177]}},"id":"b609e524-f77b-493f-8713-715846980d9c","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{"plot":{"id":"a51e3dcc-2662-4735-b1ca-48832a7264b6","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"}},"id":"351ccde3-723b-445d-8765-6cdcede88d0d","type":"SaveTool"},{"attributes":{"bottom_units":"screen","fill_alpha":{"value":0.5},"fill_color":{"value":"lightgrey"},"left_units":"screen","level":"overlay","line_alpha":{"value":1.0},"line_color":{"value":"black"},"line_dash":[4,4],"line_width":{"value":2},"plot":null,"render_mode":"css","right_units":"screen","top_units":"screen"},"id":"521e13fb-9301-4c4f-9622-2a15f6666f88","type":"BoxAnnotation"},{"attributes":{"axis_label":"95735 Human Apoptosense M30, pg/ml","axis_label_text_font_style":"bold","formatter":{"id":"30d8adbc-1bbd-49f9-9056-daf8cbc2920b","type":"PrintfTickFormatter"},"plot":{"id":"e44c3f42-efae-400d-a997-de22cc1d9be2","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"edb441a1-4fdb-441f-82d7-ef5c9bf89a7b","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"7f6c26c5-6c0f-4b82-b54e-6ae035a42551","type":"LinearAxis"},{"attributes":{"plot":{"id":"a51e3dcc-2662-4735-b1ca-48832a7264b6","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"59097f65-8f85-4e09-a80b-af85f92666ea","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"43d8cc65-3140-400a-adbf-301b93cd21fb","type":"Grid"},{"attributes":{"children":[{"id":"a51e3dcc-2662-4735-b1ca-48832a7264b6","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},{"id":"64a90e8d-fce9-4bbd-b044-1ceda097ba2d","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},{"id":"e44c3f42-efae-400d-a997-de22cc1d9be2","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"}]},"id":"fa51df2d-c281-4559-9fa2-05403688a06a","type":"Column"},{"attributes":{"bounds":[0,null],"callback":null,"end":2.5},"id":"4a564014-2efa-4bc1-9fc9-66d4a722c4da","type":"Range1d"},{"attributes":{"callback":null},"id":"5e810fb6-8963-47a2-b1ef-4cbf2976a259","type":"DataRange1d"},{"attributes":{"callback":null,"column_names":["x","y"],"data":{"x":[0.5,1,2,4,6],"y":[0.183,0.436,0.771,1.453,2.177]}},"id":"83b66900-4cd4-4d1c-8f66-60c8665f23e6","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{"plot":{"id":"a51e3dcc-2662-4735-b1ca-48832a7264b6","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"}},"id":"a0a4a475-1273-44b6-b312-2e9e7a3db071","type":"WheelZoomTool"},{"attributes":{"bounds":[0,null],"callback":null,"end":2.5},"id":"be0121bb-c66c-4f58-bcc6-60dee73e3906","type":"Range1d"},{"attributes":{"format":"%d pmol"},"id":"e2f15250-4359-477a-993a-bace1c43204e","type":"PrintfTickFormatter"},{"attributes":{"items":[{"id":"6f8cc559-bea7-4209-99c5-7037deead29c","type":"LegendItem"}],"label_text_font_style":"bold","location":"top_left","plot":{"id":"64a90e8d-fce9-4bbd-b044-1ceda097ba2d","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"}},"id":"64422ead-b565-4cf7-ad62-71be497e3ad3","type":"Legend"},{"attributes":{"line_color":{"value":"#1f77b4"},"line_width":{"value":4},"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"6951ff93-78b0-4410-908a-b6235b52c745","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"fill_alpha":{"value":0.1},"fill_color":{"value":"#1f77b4"},"line_alpha":{"value":0.1},"line_color":{"value":"#1f77b4"},"size":{"units":"screen","value":8},"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"801ad24a-8d5e-4a6d-bce2-c12c6cc76c28","type":"Circle"},{"attributes":{"callback":null,"column_names":["x","y"],"data":{"x":[9.375,18.75,37.5,75,150],"y":[0.183,0.436,0.771,1.453,2.177]}},"id":"fb013b9d-e02a-4dcf-8a39-53fd28e06b0a","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":{"value":0.1},"line_color":{"value":"#1f77b4"},"line_width":{"value":4},"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"5c016a30-4628-476d-8271-db0cf0bb814f","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"axis_label":"95734 Human Free carnitine(F-C)\n, pg/ml","axis_label_text_font_style":"bold","formatter":{"id":"7611152e-8efd-48a7-9d70-dd30e237ab41","type":"PrintfTickFormatter"},"plot":{"id":"64a90e8d-fce9-4bbd-b044-1ceda097ba2d","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"ab09a83a-42c4-44e8-919d-30796ac60bfe","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"ec75fa99-4693-4ca9-91fa-dd33ed3e20ef","type":"LinearAxis"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":{"value":0.1},"line_color":{"value":"#1f77b4"},"line_width":{"value":4},"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"e6565ecc-8d83-440f-af86-88b488066471","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{},"id":"ab09a83a-42c4-44e8-919d-30796ac60bfe","type":"BasicTicker"},{"attributes":{"plot":{"id":"a51e3dcc-2662-4735-b1ca-48832a7264b6","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"}},"id":"fb5572e9-b038-4e5b-8295-3ad612a31885","type":"ResetTool"},{"attributes":{},"id":"e22b7b7a-2d18-4526-80fa-e3001352a319","type":"ToolEvents"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":{"value":0.1},"line_color":{"value":"#1f77b4"},"line_width":{"value":4},"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"99213003-bdf1-4278-b202-457d8f4b2e7f","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"label":{"value":"75x^4 - 542.17x\u00b3 + 396.6x\u00b2 + 131.48x + 2.0519"},"renderers":[{"id":"d7941470-1f87-439f-a797-accc78f7cc69","type":"GlyphRenderer"}]},"id":"2accad8a-abf2-468b-8b6a-2e03bc675907","type":"LegendItem"},{"attributes":{"dimension":1,"plot":{"id":"a51e3dcc-2662-4735-b1ca-48832a7264b6","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"e4c1cac9-ed55-4ac3-8af2-e2390e64ddaa","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"8e631177-2a67-4aab-8e2b-5b826bf4208b","type":"Grid"},{"attributes":{"plot":{"id":"64a90e8d-fce9-4bbd-b044-1ceda097ba2d","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"}},"id":"3a0a1eb4-3e6d-46b8-ab89-cf8f4f1cbe2a","type":"PanTool"},{"attributes":{"plot":{"id":"64a90e8d-fce9-4bbd-b044-1ceda097ba2d","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"}},"id":"91dcbc0c-4c67-43e6-83f0-734c4e51c422","type":"WheelZoomTool"},{"attributes":{"plot":{"id":"64a90e8d-fce9-4bbd-b044-1ceda097ba2d","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"}},"id":"0d69a258-4b25-4097-b2fc-4c8ccee39867","type":"HelpTool"},{"attributes":{"bounds":[0,null],"callback":null,"end":2.5},"id":"f2efd5a3-a4d7-45b3-9dc1-7bda5ec259f5","type":"Range1d"},{"attributes":{"plot":{"id":"e44c3f42-efae-400d-a997-de22cc1d9be2","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"edb441a1-4fdb-441f-82d7-ef5c9bf89a7b","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"3df0545d-95fb-4a61-96d8-044988c435ee","type":"Grid"},{"attributes":{"callback":null,"column_names":["x","y"],"data":{"x":[9.375,18.75,37.5,75,150],"y":[0.183,0.436,0.771,1.453,2.177]}},"id":"43064e70-6d90-4e15-a701-691886d6c98d","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"f80ed589-aa96-4e2b-b357-512934b32548","type":"ColumnDataSource"},"glyph":{"id":"54443d79-4bda-436a-b85c-b327adce5a92","type":"Circle"},"hover_glyph":null,"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"801ad24a-8d5e-4a6d-bce2-c12c6cc76c28","type":"Circle"},"selection_glyph":null},"id":"630f3983-2a3f-4aaa-bfca-49954efc0c25","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{"plot":{"id":"e44c3f42-efae-400d-a997-de22cc1d9be2","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"}},"id":"3ab3dce1-6b3d-49d9-b1ea-4081b39446f5","type":"HelpTool"},{"attributes":{"overlay":{"id":"db8c5b58-879a-4a7f-bfe3-e9dd3b9c7d1d","type":"BoxAnnotation"},"plot":{"id":"64a90e8d-fce9-4bbd-b044-1ceda097ba2d","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"}},"id":"93e96ad3-8068-48a1-9f6f-2236e0ede821","type":"BoxZoomTool"},{"attributes":{"items":[{"id":"e52ec974-f942-44a5-bc88-eee9aaeb26ad","type":"LegendItem"}],"label_text_font_style":"bold","location":"top_left","plot":{"id":"e44c3f42-efae-400d-a997-de22cc1d9be2","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"}},"id":"29a55b43-6628-4c9b-88f2-5241cca6911f","type":"Legend"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"b609e524-f77b-493f-8713-715846980d9c","type":"ColumnDataSource"},"glyph":{"id":"8473f88f-cf74-4f31-b31a-d2c6db34374a","type":"Line"},"hover_glyph":null,"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"5c016a30-4628-476d-8271-db0cf0bb814f","type":"Line"},"selection_glyph":null},"id":"58aa88a4-8ff8-4f52-8a36-4ae90b87d9fb","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{},"id":"59097f65-8f85-4e09-a80b-af85f92666ea","type":"BasicTicker"},{"attributes":{"plot":{"id":"e44c3f42-efae-400d-a997-de22cc1d9be2","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"}},"id":"b6871fce-fdc4-4662-bb5d-85e9b7a4ad1e","type":"ResetTool"},{"attributes":{"fill_alpha":{"value":0.1},"fill_color":{"value":"#1f77b4"},"line_alpha":{"value":0.1},"line_color":{"value":"#1f77b4"},"size":{"units":"screen","value":8},"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"23334a4d-0a36-4888-a59f-a4a6250bd69c","type":"Circle"},{"attributes":{"callback":null},"id":"5b8d0607-7472-4e11-ae18-7254bfc50db3","type":"DataRange1d"},{"attributes":{},"id":"2e431824-d01c-4cce-abac-39320d6671b2","type":"BasicTicker"},{"attributes":{"axis_label":"95724 Human copeptin\n, pmol/L","axis_label_text_font_style":"bold","formatter":{"id":"e2f15250-4359-477a-993a-bace1c43204e","type":"PrintfTickFormatter"},"plot":{"id":"a51e3dcc-2662-4735-b1ca-48832a7264b6","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"59097f65-8f85-4e09-a80b-af85f92666ea","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"ca22b639-f183-4932-9035-6575f43477d4","type":"LinearAxis"},{"attributes":{"plot":{"id":"e44c3f42-efae-400d-a997-de22cc1d9be2","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"}},"id":"5d058e2a-1b8a-4886-bc0e-40a209e5c190","type":"SaveTool"},{"attributes":{"items":[{"id":"2accad8a-abf2-468b-8b6a-2e03bc675907","type":"LegendItem"}],"label_text_font_style":"bold","location":"top_left","plot":{"id":"a51e3dcc-2662-4735-b1ca-48832a7264b6","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"}},"id":"ba8c08f8-eb6a-430e-a73c-4293329538cc","type":"Legend"},{"attributes":{"plot":{"id":"e44c3f42-efae-400d-a997-de22cc1d9be2","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"}},"id":"77ca8c4c-cdfb-47af-a837-7c76e0338f7e","type":"WheelZoomTool"},{"attributes":{},"id":"edb441a1-4fdb-441f-82d7-ef5c9bf89a7b","type":"BasicTicker"},{"attributes":{"callback":null,"column_names":["x","y"],"data":{"x":[10,20,40,80,160],"y":[0.183,0.436,0.771,1.453,2.177]}},"id":"f80ed589-aa96-4e2b-b357-512934b32548","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{"background_fill_alpha":{"value":0.8},"below":[{"id":"ca22b639-f183-4932-9035-6575f43477d4","type":"LinearAxis"}],"left":[{"id":"6862c7c5-cb85-4243-9c7b-9a49642710f8","type":"LinearAxis"}],"plot_width":900,"renderers":[{"id":"ca22b639-f183-4932-9035-6575f43477d4","type":"LinearAxis"},{"id":"43d8cc65-3140-400a-adbf-301b93cd21fb","type":"Grid"},{"id":"6862c7c5-cb85-4243-9c7b-9a49642710f8","type":"LinearAxis"},{"id":"8e631177-2a67-4aab-8e2b-5b826bf4208b","type":"Grid"},{"id":"521e13fb-9301-4c4f-9622-2a15f6666f88","type":"BoxAnnotation"},{"id":"ba8c08f8-eb6a-430e-a73c-4293329538cc","type":"Legend"},{"id":"d7941470-1f87-439f-a797-accc78f7cc69","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"id":"038d2c03-db1f-4246-969a-2f003bc58214","type":"GlyphRenderer"}],"title":{"id":"f70da64c-6a60-4c81-ac9c-486574b9c4ed","type":"Title"},"tool_events":{"id":"e22b7b7a-2d18-4526-80fa-e3001352a319","type":"ToolEvents"},"toolbar":{"id":"f75e2cb9-f423-4383-a41d-638ff4a5a417","type":"Toolbar"},"x_range":{"id":"29683b67-b091-4a62-ab1f-d40b1289e9f4","type":"DataRange1d"},"y_range":{"id":"f2efd5a3-a4d7-45b3-9dc1-7bda5ec259f5","type":"Range1d"}},"id":"a51e3dcc-2662-4735-b1ca-48832a7264b6","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},{"attributes":{"bottom_units":"screen","fill_alpha":{"value":0.5},"fill_color":{"value":"lightgrey"},"left_units":"screen","level":"overlay","line_alpha":{"value":1.0},"line_color":{"value":"black"},"line_dash":[4,4],"line_width":{"value":2},"plot":null,"render_mode":"css","right_units":"screen","top_units":"screen"},"id":"db8c5b58-879a-4a7f-bfe3-e9dd3b9c7d1d","type":"BoxAnnotation"},{"attributes":{"plot":null,"text":""},"id":"ba81564b-0c23-4a9e-826e-e43201b0e449","type":"Title"},{"attributes":{"fill_color":{"value":"white"},"line_color":{"value":"#1f77b4"},"size":{"units":"screen","value":8},"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"54443d79-4bda-436a-b85c-b327adce5a92","type":"Circle"},{"attributes":{"fill_color":{"value":"white"},"line_color":{"value":"#1f77b4"},"size":{"units":"screen","value":8},"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"a8506a17-fef3-45ea-8118-749941f73322","type":"Circle"},{"attributes":{"plot":{"id":"a51e3dcc-2662-4735-b1ca-48832a7264b6","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"}},"id":"35150a0a-6a13-4fb1-9d65-680844b108fd","type":"HelpTool"},{"attributes":{"format":"%d pg"},"id":"30d8adbc-1bbd-49f9-9056-daf8cbc2920b","type":"PrintfTickFormatter"},{"attributes":{"plot":{"id":"64a90e8d-fce9-4bbd-b044-1ceda097ba2d","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"}},"id":"ed65518e-1887-4053-bb39-3d162c719899","type":"ResetTool"},{"attributes":{"label":{"value":"75x^4 - 542.17x\u00b3 + 396.6x\u00b2 + 131.48x + 2.0519"},"renderers":[{"id":"58aa88a4-8ff8-4f52-8a36-4ae90b87d9fb","type":"GlyphRenderer"}]},"id":"e52ec974-f942-44a5-bc88-eee9aaeb26ad","type":"LegendItem"},{"attributes":{"background_fill_alpha":{"value":0.8},"below":[{"id":"ec75fa99-4693-4ca9-91fa-dd33ed3e20ef","type":"LinearAxis"}],"left":[{"id":"2c445319-62e1-42a3-b270-59425c3c4100","type":"LinearAxis"}],"plot_width":900,"renderers":[{"id":"ec75fa99-4693-4ca9-91fa-dd33ed3e20ef","type":"LinearAxis"},{"id":"b2cbd3ba-7dbd-400e-9971-227edc77fed7","type":"Grid"},{"id":"2c445319-62e1-42a3-b270-59425c3c4100","type":"LinearAxis"},{"id":"291ccc16-e4c1-4f7e-bae5-af652e9fd098","type":"Grid"},{"id":"db8c5b58-879a-4a7f-bfe3-e9dd3b9c7d1d","type":"BoxAnnotation"},{"id":"64422ead-b565-4cf7-ad62-71be497e3ad3","type":"Legend"},{"id":"9b3e35b4-210e-4989-a5c3-8015c3ae34bc","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"id":"3771367d-7eac-4366-82eb-2a6ae0581aad","type":"GlyphRenderer"}],"title":{"id":"e437cbca-8f2b-4cd4-83d8-b2c020726684","type":"Title"},"tool_events":{"id":"42e06622-2cec-43bc-8b0b-37606b4e2ed0","type":"ToolEvents"},"toolbar":{"id":"7c537b7a-60fc-4ed7-9f37-2e26d7f7ef84","type":"Toolbar"},"x_range":{"id":"5e810fb6-8963-47a2-b1ef-4cbf2976a259","type":"DataRange1d"},"y_range":{"id":"4a564014-2efa-4bc1-9fc9-66d4a722c4da","type":"Range1d"}},"id":"64a90e8d-fce9-4bbd-b044-1ceda097ba2d","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},{"attributes":{"axis_label":"OD=450nm","axis_label_text_font_style":"bold","formatter":{"id":"e4ec96e3-88cc-4a38-9c98-013e60302040","type":"PrintfTickFormatter"},"plot":{"id":"64a90e8d-fce9-4bbd-b044-1ceda097ba2d","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"2e431824-d01c-4cce-abac-39320d6671b2","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"2c445319-62e1-42a3-b270-59425c3c4100","type":"LinearAxis"},{"attributes":{"overlay":{"id":"65d909ea-fabf-4424-9b9c-08853c798990","type":"BoxAnnotation"},"plot":{"id":"e44c3f42-efae-400d-a997-de22cc1d9be2","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"}},"id":"fdd8248a-9231-4b1b-96b2-50a93cc377d6","type":"BoxZoomTool"},{"attributes":{"overlay":{"id":"521e13fb-9301-4c4f-9622-2a15f6666f88","type":"BoxAnnotation"},"plot":{"id":"a51e3dcc-2662-4735-b1ca-48832a7264b6","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"}},"id":"d311ebd6-2b3c-407f-ae8d-921f407eb08d","type":"BoxZoomTool"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"43064e70-6d90-4e15-a701-691886d6c98d","type":"ColumnDataSource"},"glyph":{"id":"6951ff93-78b0-4410-908a-b6235b52c745","type":"Line"},"hover_glyph":null,"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"99213003-bdf1-4278-b202-457d8f4b2e7f","type":"Line"},"selection_glyph":null},"id":"9b3e35b4-210e-4989-a5c3-8015c3ae34bc","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{"callback":null},"id":"29683b67-b091-4a62-ab1f-d40b1289e9f4","type":"DataRange1d"},{"attributes":{"plot":{"id":"64a90e8d-fce9-4bbd-b044-1ceda097ba2d","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"}},"id":"4091c142-49a2-4042-9cbd-705b4fba8fb3","type":"SaveTool"},{"attributes":{"axis_label":"OD=450nm","axis_label_text_font_style":"bold","formatter":{"id":"210d7bd4-012f-4d10-8822-2e1e3c576cad","type":"PrintfTickFormatter"},"plot":{"id":"a51e3dcc-2662-4735-b1ca-48832a7264b6","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"e4c1cac9-ed55-4ac3-8af2-e2390e64ddaa","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"6862c7c5-cb85-4243-9c7b-9a49642710f8","type":"LinearAxis"},{"attributes":{"bottom_units":"screen","fill_alpha":{"value":0.5},"fill_color":{"value":"lightgrey"},"left_units":"screen","level":"overlay","line_alpha":{"value":1.0},"line_color":{"value":"black"},"line_dash":[4,4],"line_width":{"value":2},"plot":null,"render_mode":"css","right_units":"screen","top_units":"screen"},"id":"65d909ea-fabf-4424-9b9c-08853c798990","type":"BoxAnnotation"},{"attributes":{"format":"%.1f L"},"id":"210d7bd4-012f-4d10-8822-2e1e3c576cad","type":"PrintfTickFormatter"},{"attributes":{},"id":"9c1cc749-78d3-499e-8166-9d0b4ca3c80e","type":"ToolEvents"},{"attributes":{"line_color":{"value":"#1f77b4"},"line_width":{"value":4},"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"8473f88f-cf74-4f31-b31a-d2c6db34374a","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"plot":null,"text":""},"id":"e437cbca-8f2b-4cd4-83d8-b2c020726684","type":"Title"},{"attributes":{"plot":{"id":"a51e3dcc-2662-4735-b1ca-48832a7264b6","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"}},"id":"9f06704d-ad5c-45c2-aa0d-08c4327129aa","type":"PanTool"},{"attributes":{"active_drag":"auto","active_scroll":"auto","active_tap":"auto","logo":null,"tools":[{"id":"3a0a1eb4-3e6d-46b8-ab89-cf8f4f1cbe2a","type":"PanTool"},{"id":"91dcbc0c-4c67-43e6-83f0-734c4e51c422","type":"WheelZoomTool"},{"id":"93e96ad3-8068-48a1-9f6f-2236e0ede821","type":"BoxZoomTool"},{"id":"4091c142-49a2-4042-9cbd-705b4fba8fb3","type":"SaveTool"},{"id":"ed65518e-1887-4053-bb39-3d162c719899","type":"ResetTool"},{"id":"0d69a258-4b25-4097-b2fc-4c8ccee39867","type":"HelpTool"}]},"id":"7c537b7a-60fc-4ed7-9f37-2e26d7f7ef84","type":"Toolbar"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"32b7f2b8-c72e-4caf-982d-49753e787111","type":"ColumnDataSource"},"glyph":{"id":"eda96e22-e71f-4452-a30f-b9a4b8718831","type":"Circle"},"hover_glyph":null,"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"bb128c3f-68fb-4464-9d3f-c188b2ce8614","type":"Circle"},"selection_glyph":null},"id":"038d2c03-db1f-4246-969a-2f003bc58214","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{"plot":{"id":"e44c3f42-efae-400d-a997-de22cc1d9be2","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"}},"id":"9273eb57-9cd5-47ec-b61a-391ca387cf96","type":"PanTool"},{"attributes":{"background_fill_alpha":{"value":0.8},"below":[{"id":"7f6c26c5-6c0f-4b82-b54e-6ae035a42551","type":"LinearAxis"}],"left":[{"id":"bf5574c8-01bd-4feb-9dc1-f2d43e3ff684","type":"LinearAxis"}],"plot_width":900,"renderers":[{"id":"7f6c26c5-6c0f-4b82-b54e-6ae035a42551","type":"LinearAxis"},{"id":"3df0545d-95fb-4a61-96d8-044988c435ee","type":"Grid"},{"id":"bf5574c8-01bd-4feb-9dc1-f2d43e3ff684","type":"LinearAxis"},{"id":"03fd8f50-9f84-414a-921e-f9215101a4d3","type":"Grid"},{"id":"65d909ea-fabf-4424-9b9c-08853c798990","type":"BoxAnnotation"},{"id":"29a55b43-6628-4c9b-88f2-5241cca6911f","type":"Legend"},{"id":"58aa88a4-8ff8-4f52-8a36-4ae90b87d9fb","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"id":"630f3983-2a3f-4aaa-bfca-49954efc0c25","type":"GlyphRenderer"}],"title":{"id":"ba81564b-0c23-4a9e-826e-e43201b0e449","type":"Title"},"tool_events":{"id":"9c1cc749-78d3-499e-8166-9d0b4ca3c80e","type":"ToolEvents"},"toolbar":{"id":"d81630f8-b9ed-4cce-907b-0141d2e05635","type":"Toolbar"},"x_range":{"id":"5b8d0607-7472-4e11-ae18-7254bfc50db3","type":"DataRange1d"},"y_range":{"id":"be0121bb-c66c-4f58-bcc6-60dee73e3906","type":"Range1d"}},"id":"e44c3f42-efae-400d-a997-de22cc1d9be2","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},{"attributes":{},"id":"42e06622-2cec-43bc-8b0b-37606b4e2ed0","type":"ToolEvents"},{"attributes":{"plot":null,"text":""},"id":"f70da64c-6a60-4c81-ac9c-486574b9c4ed","type":"Title"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"fb013b9d-e02a-4dcf-8a39-53fd28e06b0a","type":"ColumnDataSource"},"glyph":{"id":"a8506a17-fef3-45ea-8118-749941f73322","type":"Circle"},"hover_glyph":null,"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"23334a4d-0a36-4888-a59f-a4a6250bd69c","type":"Circle"},"selection_glyph":null},"id":"3771367d-7eac-4366-82eb-2a6ae0581aad","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{"line_color":{"value":"#1f77b4"},"line_width":{"value":4},"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"5e858549-3ff5-41e0-b90c-d3a6976a3686","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"format":"%d pg"},"id":"7611152e-8efd-48a7-9d70-dd30e237ab41","type":"PrintfTickFormatter"},{"attributes":{"dimension":1,"plot":{"id":"e44c3f42-efae-400d-a997-de22cc1d9be2","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"8ab7c0bd-3ec6-4ba1-992b-9b1d81e19180","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"03fd8f50-9f84-414a-921e-f9215101a4d3","type":"Grid"},{"attributes":{},"id":"8ab7c0bd-3ec6-4ba1-992b-9b1d81e19180","type":"BasicTicker"},{"attributes":{"active_drag":"auto","active_scroll":"auto","active_tap":"auto","logo":null,"tools":[{"id":"9273eb57-9cd5-47ec-b61a-391ca387cf96","type":"PanTool"},{"id":"77ca8c4c-cdfb-47af-a837-7c76e0338f7e","type":"WheelZoomTool"},{"id":"fdd8248a-9231-4b1b-96b2-50a93cc377d6","type":"BoxZoomTool"},{"id":"5d058e2a-1b8a-4886-bc0e-40a209e5c190","type":"SaveTool"},{"id":"b6871fce-fdc4-4662-bb5d-85e9b7a4ad1e","type":"ResetTool"},{"id":"3ab3dce1-6b3d-49d9-b1ea-4081b39446f5","type":"HelpTool"}]},"id":"d81630f8-b9ed-4cce-907b-0141d2e05635","type":"Toolbar"},{"attributes":{"active_drag":"auto","active_scroll":"auto","active_tap":"auto","logo":null,"tools":[{"id":"9f06704d-ad5c-45c2-aa0d-08c4327129aa","type":"PanTool"},{"id":"a0a4a475-1273-44b6-b312-2e9e7a3db071","type":"WheelZoomTool"},{"id":"d311ebd6-2b3c-407f-ae8d-921f407eb08d","type":"BoxZoomTool"},{"id":"351ccde3-723b-445d-8765-6cdcede88d0d","type":"SaveTool"},{"id":"fb5572e9-b038-4e5b-8295-3ad612a31885","type":"ResetTool"},{"id":"35150a0a-6a13-4fb1-9d65-680844b108fd","type":"HelpTool"}]},"id":"f75e2cb9-f423-4383-a41d-638ff4a5a417","type":"Toolbar"}],"root_ids":["fa51df2d-c281-4559-9fa2-05403688a06a"]},"title":"Bokeh Application","version":"0.12.4"}};
              var render_items = [{"docid":"2797a004-7f17-48fa-b80f-105be766d58d","elementid":"c5c2aae1-5936-42f6-b4e3-9bc4b46efd06","modelid":"fa51df2d-c281-4559-9fa2-05403688a06a"}];
              
              Bokeh.embed.embed_items(docs_json, render_items);
            });
          };
          if (document.readyState != "loading") fn();
          else document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn);
        })();
        
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can't do it manually for a long time,
because needed a thousands of images.

p.s.
to @e1che
I've fixed some things in our code:

```
for i in range(len(saves)):
    print i
    saves[i].click()
    saves[i].send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

looks simpler and better, but also don't work correctly.

Comment: When I load the page, I see the 3 initial graphs but I never see the 50 that come later. How is it supposed to work?

Comment: Yes, I know, I've attached the html file with only 3 graphs,
You misunderstood me. The html files with a dozens of graphs are on my laptop, and not attached there, I just wanted to mention about a scale, and performance issues.

Comment: You should probably update the question because your comments around the 50 graphs is not clear. I think I understand now though. I've updated my answer to include the separate files but it should work with multiple graphs in each file.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem comes from you gives a "new" url to your driver.
You should simplify a bit your foreach loop.

```
for i in range(len(saves)):
    print i
    elem_loop = elem[i]
    saves_loop = saves[i]
    saves_loop[i].click()
    elem_loop.send_keys(Keys.ENTER) // elem_loop[i] ? you click on the same element for each image ?
```

Comment: thanks, but this snippet will not be working, because 
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("bk-tool-icon-save")
elem is one element, not a list of elements.

Comment: for i in range(len(saves)):
    print i
    saves[i].click()
    saves[i].send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

looks simpler and better, but also don't work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the 50 images that you refer to in the question but the main issue you are having is that you are reloading the page before clicking all the save buttons on the page. You can fix that with the code below.

```
// files is an array of string which is the path to the files on disk
for file in files
    driver.get(file)
    for e in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("bk-tool-icon-save"):
        e.click()
```

This should save off all the loaded images. Once you provide more details on how/when the other 50 images are loaded, we can answer that portion. You should just wait until all the images are loaded and the code above will work and save all images.

Also, `elem` is just the first element from the `saves` collection so there's no need to store both. I'm not sure the purpose of the `send_keys()`... it shouldn't be needed so I removed it also.